# Elasticsearch keeps overwriting existing data on ebs volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, terraform

I have an aws instance running ELK server on it, with an EBS attached. All mamanged by Terraform.

Elasticsearch's `path.data` is pointed towards the mounted dir of EBS. Data is stored as `/ebs_vol/nodes/0/indices`. Works perfectly fine.

**The Problem:**

When I destroy and re-create the instance (with Terraform), the ELK server is all set **BUT** it overwrites the `/ebs_vol/nodes/0/indices` and all the data present in elasticsearch before destroy/create is gone now.

**Expected:**

After aws_instance destroy/create elasticsearch data should persist.

It would be great if someone can help!

Comment: Are you sure that the EBS volume attached to instance #2 is the same volume that was previously attached to instance #1?

Comment: @jarmod yes because terraform does not delete the volume and the volume id `vol-1235...` keeps same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the ec2 instance start script which before mounting the EBS volume created a file system on it `sudo mkfs.ext4` and it wiped all the existing content.

Hence I have done that dynamically now;

```
if sudo mount -a ; then
    echo "Mount succeeded"
else
    echo "Mount failed"
    sudo mkfs.ext4 $EBS_DEVICE
    sudo mount -a
fi
```